# Not Getting Specific Array Returned From Map When Using Key

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a singleton class that implements a Hashmap the Map gets its arrays from resources string.xml file during instantiation. however, when I try to get an array from specific key eg
allPhrases.get(category) returns null. the array contains a category description as key and an array as value. here's the code for the Phrases class

```
public class Phrases {
    public Context context;
    public static String[] categories = {"feeling", "home", "work", "medical", "food", "activity", "common", "emergency"};
    private static Phrases phrases = null;
    public Map<String, String[]> allPhrases = new HashMap<>();

    private Phrases() {
    }

    public static Phrases getPhrases() {
        if(phrases == null) {
            phrases = new Phrases();
        }
        return phrases;
    }

    public void fetchAllPhrases(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        allPhrases.put(categories[0], res.getStringArray(R.array.feeling));
        allPhrases.put(categories[1],  res.getStringArray(R.array.home));
        allPhrases.put(categories[2], res.getStringArray(R.array.work));
        allPhrases.put(categories[3], res.getStringArray(R.array.medical));
        allPhrases.put(categories[4], res.getStringArray(R.array.food));
        allPhrases.put(categories[5], res.getStringArray(R.array.activity));
        allPhrases.put(categories[6], res.getStringArray(R.array.common));
        allPhrases.put(categories[7], res.getStringArray(R.array.emergency));
//        Log.v("PHRASES", Arrays.toString(allPhrases.toString()));
    }

    public Map<String, String[]> getAllPhrases() {
        return allPhrases;
    }
}
```

inside my fragment I get categories from user selection and then I try to use it as the key for pulling the values from hashmap in the form of objectName.getAllPhrases().get(categories) here's the class

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private FloatingActionButton addPhraseButton;
    private TextView phraseTitleTextView;
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String[] phrases;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom, container, false);
        //receive intent
        String categories = getArguments().getString("categories");

        Phrases phrasesObj = Phrases.getPhrases();
        phrasesObj.fetchAllPhrases(view.getContext());
        phrases = phrasesObj.getAllPhrases().get(categories);

        phraseTitleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.label_phrases_txtview);
        addPhraseButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_phrases_btn);
        // setting local for text to speech
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        });

        //setting adapter and listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.entry_item, R.id.phrase_textview, phrases);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.phrases_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paren, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = phrases[position];
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null, null);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did `getArguments().getString("categories")` return when you debugged?

Comment: thanks.. appreciated